# Update var on event jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I've got something like this:

```
var value = '.$ures['health'].';
$({value: value}).animate({value: value+10}, {
   duration: 1000,
   easing:"swing",
   step: function() { 
      $("#life").text(Math.round(this.value));
   }
});
```

So how to change `var value` value when the animation is started, so the next counting will start from the new value?

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle would srurely help to see what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the value of `value` (not a good name for a variable) to the updated value in the step function, the last one will stick, and the `value` variable will be updated :

```
var value = '.$ures['health'].';

$({value: value}).animate({value: value + 10}, 
   {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function (now) {
        var v = parseInt(now,10);
        $("#life").text(v);
        value = v;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/csZJJ/1/)

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you build a jQuery object from a anonymous object ?

Comment: @Virus721 - check the fiddle, and you'll find out !

Comment: It's working in fiddle but it doesn't in my project.

check out the entire code..

Comment: $(".carrot").click(function (){
$("#carrot").attr("src", "imgs/loader.gif");
$.ajax({
url: "regen.php?a=hp"
}).done(function (){
$("#carrot").attr("src", "imgs/icons/carrot.png");
var value = '.$ures['health'].';
go();
function go() {
$({value: value}).animate({value: value + 10}, {
 duration: 1000,
 easing: "swing",
 step: function (now) { 
  var v = parseInt(now,10);
  $("#life").text(v);
  value = v;
 }
});
}
});
});

Comment: It still doesn't tell me what it is. A jQuery object is supposed to represent a set of references to existing dom elements, not a object like that one passed to$().

Comment: however I put it outside the ajax action and now it works. :))

Comment: @Virus721 - `$()` is just a function named `$` that accepts parameters, in this case an object and not a selector string.

Comment: I know it's a function, but what does it represent when you pass an object to it instead of a query string ?